# How to read data from a table in threepenny-gui?

Tags: haskell, threepenny-gui

Let's say I want every `<tr>` to be an object, with its children `<td>` to be the fields of that object. So I'm looking for something like this:

```
getListFromTable :: Window -> Element -> [Thing]
getListFromTable w table = do
  rows <- getElementsByClassName w "thing-row"
  -- BS starts here, lets say fromFields creates a Thing from ... fields.
  attrList = [ fromFields [ r # get UI.children ] | r <- rows ]
  return attrList
```

However, I just can't seem to get the types right, and I suppose I don't even really know what `get UI.children` does, since it's not something like gives me an obvious type like [Element].

Answer (score 1):

As the type

```
children :: WriteAttr Element [Element]
```

indicates, this attribute is write-only. As of threepenny-gui version 0.6, it's not possible to obtain a list of all child elements of a particular Element.

Comment: Is there a reason for that to be so? I'm assuming this also means there isn't a way for me to do what I'm asking, at least if I were simply given a table.

Comment: The reason is mainly that I haven't implemented it yet. I don't know what that means for your project, because I have trouble parsing your question.